# Can't connect to Xamarin.iOS running on Mac from Windows machine

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xamarin

The diagnostic view fails in the third-to-last step (out of 11):

**Establishing a stateful connection to Mac build host via HTTP**. => *failed*

The *Details* section shows:

**Connection could not be established. Unable to get InfoRecord. Unable to get SDK status.**

I have double checked all recommendations in the "Actions" section: latest version of Xamarin.iOS installed, no other instance of Visual Studio connected, firewall disabled, Xamarin.iOS activated.

Both machines have Xamarin Studio 4.0.

Here are the last few entries from `~/Library/logs/Xamarin/MonoTouchVS/mtbserver.log`:

```
[01-Mar-2013 17:52:24] Server IP Address : 10.1.0.199
[01-Mar-2013 17:54:44] mtbserver: No KEEPALIVE command, exiting...
[01-Mar-2013 17:54:48] Apple SDK developer root: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
[01-Mar-2013 17:54:48] Server IP Address : 10.1.0.199
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned by Veux below, using a proxy on Windows can cause this issue. Curiously, Fiddler2 can still work as a reverse proxy for the device (iPhone or the simulator) if "Capture Traffic" is disabled.

Comment: Could you check the ~/Library/logs/Xamarin/MonoTouchVS/mtbserver.log file? there is any other information there?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? its happening on my side as well.

Comment: @josemiguel.torres: I added the last few entries in that log file to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the some problem, all was configured well but got the same error.
The solution for me, was to disable the proxy! on the windows machine

Hope that will help  you

Comment: Fiddler2 was the culprit. As soon as I disabled it, everything worked fine. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

- Check if you have Xcode installed on /Applications/Xcode.app
- Check if the Documentation of Xcode is installed.(http://screencast.com/t/f3Kku2iggDeY)
- Check if this path exist on your Mac.

  ```
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Documentation/
  ```
- If is empty, create a symbolic link from DocSets (http://screencast.com/t/dmN00AYw9k)

  ```
  ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/
  ```
- to

  ```
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Documentation/DocSets
  ```